# QT - pixmap artefacts on drag

Tags: c++, qt

I have an issue with pixmaps created for drag events. For drag events of my derived QGraphicsRectItem I create a semi-transparent pixmap from that item.

In the debug build everything looks fine.

[image]

But in the release build the drag pixmap has some periodic and random artefacts

[image]

here is the code:

```
QPixmap MyGraphicsRectItem::toPixmap() const
{
   QRect r = boundingRect().toRect();
   QPixmap pixmap(r.width(), r.height());
   QColor dragColor(color);
   dragColor.setAlphaF(0.5);

   QPainter painter;
   painter.begin(&pixmap);

   painter.fillRect(pixmap.rect(), dragColor);
   painter.setPen(Qt::white);

   QFont font("SegoeUI");
   font.setBold(true);

   painter.setFont(font);
   painter.drawText(pixmap.rect(), QString(" ") + textItem->toPlainText());

   if (pixItem != nullptr) {
       painter.setOpacity(0.5);
       painter.drawPixmap(pixItem->pos(), pixItem->pixmap());
   }

   painter.end();

   return pixmap;
}
```

Could that be a kind of memory issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QPixmap is initialized with uninitialized data. In Debug, this is often set to a fixed pattern, but in Release it is garbage.

You should fill the pixmap with transparent color before using it.

> QPixmap::QPixmap(int width, int height)
>
> Constructs a pixmap with the given width and height. If either width or height is zero, a null pixmap is constructed.
>
> **Warning:** This will create a QPixmap with uninitialized data. Call fill() to fill the pixmap with an appropriate color before drawing onto it with QPainter.

(From [Qt Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#QPixmap-2))

Comment: RTFM... Thank you, now everything looks as it supposed to look.